# .Net WebAPI returning Protocol Buffer: Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type

Tags: serialization, protocol-buffers, protocol-buffers-3

I have a `*.proto` file that defines two messages: `MyRequest` and `MyResponse`.  This is defined in a common .NET Standard 2.0 library and uses the following NuGet packages:

```
    <PackageReference Include="Google.Protobuf" Version="3.18.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc" Version="2.40.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Grpc.Tools" Version="2.40.0">
```

### The Server

I have a .NET Framework (4.8) WebAPI and the following Action Method:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FetchSomeData()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
    {
        await content.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        MyRequest request = MyRequest.Parser.ParseFrom(bytes);

        MyResponse response = await SomeMethodAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] responseByteArray = response.ToByteArray();
        return this.Ok(responseByteArray);
    }
}
```

So this successfully receives a `MyRequest` object sent *via* HttpPost, and based on the data in that object, generates a `MyResponse` object and returns that.

### The Client

I have a .Net 5 client that consumes this service with an HttpClient:

```
// Prepare Request
MyRequest webRequest = new() { ... };
byte[] byteArray = webRequest.ToByteArray();
ByteArrayContent byteContent = new(byteArray);

// Send data
HttpClient client = this.HttpClientFactory.CreateClient("Blah");
HttpResponseMessage webResponse = await client.PostAsync(new Uri("...", UriKind.Relative), byteContent).ConfigureAwait(false);

// Read response
HttpContent content = webResponse.Content;
byte[] webMethodResponseAsByteArray = await content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync().ConfigureAwait(false);
MyResponse webMethodResponse = MyResponse.Parser.ParseFrom(webMethodResponseAsByteArray);
```

The HttpClient "Blah" is only configured with a base URL and security token.

However....when I call the `ParseFrom` on the last line I get the following exception:

```
Google.Protobuf.InvalidProtocolBufferException
  HResult=0x80131620
  Message=Protocol message contained a tag with an invalid wire type.
  Source=Google.Protobuf
  StackTrace:
   at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(ParseContext& ctx)
   at Google.Protobuf.UnknownFieldSet.MergeFieldFrom(UnknownFieldSet unknownFields, ParseContext& ctx)
   at namespace.MyResponse.pb::Google.Protobuf.IBufferMessage.InternalMergeFrom(ParseContext& input) in ....
```

Not sure how to solve this one...

Comment: Can you post the hex or base-64 of the payload that is failing (i.e. `webMethodResponseAsByteArray`)? From that we can probably tell more about what has happened - and in particular, we can run it through https://protogen.marcgravell.com/decode to see whether it is valid, and what it looks like; however! If http/2 is an option, it feels like this whole thing could be a gRPC endpoint much more conveniently. (I can almost certainly help you with this, but timezones... I may be offline for the next 8 hours)

Comment: Hi Marc.  It would be great if I could use gRPC but the Server is .NET Framework (4.8) and my understanding is that only the Core of .NET flavour is compatible with gRPC.

Comment: Interestingly, in the Server `responseByteArray ` has a size of 1912 and in the Client `webMethodResponseAsByteArray` has a size of 2554.

Comment: @MarcGravell I captured the two hex strings (Server = size 1912 : "08-01-1A-44-......-72-02-45-41") and (Client = size 2552: "22-43-41-45-......-51-3D-3D-22") and pasted both into your [decode](protogen.marcgravell.com/decode) tool.  The Server one was decoded - the Client one returned nothing.

Comment: the logging needs work; it goes to the browser console right now; can you post the entire string? however, that result strongly suggests it isn't intact - is this perhaps gzip encoding?

Comment: re gRPC: it is incorrect to assume that gRPC is .NET Core only; it is more complex than that; basically, there are two separate transport layers - one by Google (unmanaged, via P/Invoke to CHTTP2) and one by Microsoft (fully managed); the **managed** option is .NET Core only; however, the *unmanaged* option (the `Grpc.Core` package) works on .NET Framework. The *library layer* (the `Grpc` package) works fine with either - all that changes is how you create the client channel and server instance. So: gRPC is *absolutely* an option for you here. All the Google docs will be showing `Grpc.Core`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237421/discussion-between-drgriff-and-marc-gravell).

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem I was facing by changing the .NET Framework (4.8) Server's method:

#### From

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> FetchSomeData()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
    {
        await content.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        MyRequest request = MyRequest.Parser.ParseFrom(bytes);

        MyResponse response = await SomeMethodAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] responseByteArray = response.ToByteArray();
        return this.Ok(responseByteArray);
    }
}
```

#### TO

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage FetchSomeData()
{
    using (var ms = new MemoryStream(2048))
    {
        await content.CopyToAsync(ms).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] bytes = ms.ToArray();
        MyRequest request = MyRequest.Parser.ParseFrom(bytes);

        MyResponse response = await SomeMethodAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false);
        byte[] responseByteArray = response.ToByteArray();
        var result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
           Content = new ByteArrayContent(responseByteArray),
        };
        return result;
    }
}
```

However, also considering the `gRPC` approach mentioned by @MarcGravell (see comments/conversation).